# Ultrafilter principle and Axiom of Dependent Choice as 'nonconstructive and constructive' components of the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, filters, constructive-mathematics

As in the title, in the book 'Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations' by Schechter, the Ultrafilter principle is presented as a nonconstructive component of the Axiom of Choice, while the Axiom of Dependent Choice as a constructive component. As the author emphasizes, anyhow, UF+DC+ZF do not imply AC.

The form I know of the two are the following:

**Ultrafilter Principle** Any proper filter can be included in an ultrafilter. That is, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a proper filter on a set $X$, then there exists an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}\supset\mathcal{F}$ on X.
**Dependent Choice (without history)**
Let $S$ be a nonempty set, let $N=\{M\subset S M\neq\emptyset\}\subset \wp(S)$ be the family of nonempty subsets of S and $f:S\rightarrow N$ a given function. 
Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)\subset S$ such that $x_{n+1}\in f(x_n)$
**Dependent Choice (with history)** Let $S_1,S_2,S_3,...$ be nonempty subsets of $S$, $F_n=\{M\subset S_{n+1} M\neq\emptyset\}$ and let $f_n: S_1\times ...\times S_n\rightarrow F_n$. Then there exists a sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ such that $x_{n+1}\in f_n(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$

Anyhow, though the idea seems interesting, I can't see why in the first place the Axiom of Dependent Choice should be more constructive than the Ultrafilter Principle, nor why the two should in some sense e complementary.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively speaking, Dependent Choice is essentially the following principle:

Suppose that there is a process choosing sets, $X_{n,y}$, such that for every $x\in X_{n,y}$, there is a non-empty set $X_{n+1,x}$. Then there is a function $f$ with domain $\Bbb N$, such that $f(n+1)\in X_{n,f(n)}$.

It lets us have inductive constructions without having to worry about specifying *exactly* "the next step", and instead just prove that such a step is possible to make.

In contrast, having non-principal ultrafilters, even just on $\omega$, requires *a lot more* choices to be made, and there is no obvious way to understand them as an iterative construction. Even with choice, working via transfinite recursion, we can easily prove that such a construction must take more than countably many steps, starting from a free filter.